# Copy contents of Excel Right Header to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is provided to show what I need to do, but I find that I cannot successfully copy the contents of the Right Header to the clipboard with VBA no matter the method or how short or elaborate the code.  Maybe it just can't be done?  I am trying to avoid using pop up boxes to capture data that users are already used to putting in the header.

```
Sub copyrightheader()

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("J1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you run that code?

Comment: Nothing is actually copied and the code fails on Paste because there is nothing in the clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.rightheader

...you can see that `PageSetup.RightHeader` reurns a `String` value, so you can assign that directly to a cell:

```
with ActiveSheet
    .Range("J1").Value = .PageSetup.RightHeader
end with
```

Comment: Thanks!!  It also captures format [&"Perpetua Titling MT,Bold"], which I can easily remove by importing it to another cell with =RIGHT .